# Can't scroll over Google chart on mobile devices

Tags: android, mobile, google-visualization

In one of our apps, we have built charts using Google Charts / Visualization Library and we noticed a problem with scrolling on mobile devices - you can only scroll by touching the background and if you touch the graph and try scrolling, you are unable to scroll. Has anyone else faced the same problem? Is there something wrong with the CSS or the way we are building the charts that we can rectify to resolve this issue?

See example: https://storage.googleapis.com/demo_file/Demo%20for%20fixed%20scroll.html

Thanks

Comment: does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16534300/5090771) help? otherwise, do the charts need to be interactive? if not, you could replace them with their own images.

Comment: Hi WhiteHat, thank you for sharing this answer, it actually resolved the issue! Thank you very much for this!!!

Comment: I read the link and solution with the object {pointer-events: none;} but I am not sure where to add this exactly. In which CSS would I apply that? I tried to add to my chart div but I still cant scroll on mobile devices.

Comment: Got it! Adding `style=pointer-events: none;` to the DIV which holds your google graph is a easy fix. How ever, if you use this option in desktop and mobile you lose all interactivity of the graphs. It might be a good solution to only add this for the mobile view to not kill the desktop interactivity as well.